# Multicast configuration for mDNS

Tags: networking, powerline-networking, chromecast, multicast, mdns

I just bought a pair of [Nexuslink 2000PT](https://nexuslinkusa.com/product/gpl-2000pt-kit/) powerline adapters. These are identical to the [Comtrend PG-9182PT](https://us.comtrend.com/products/pg-9182pt/).

It turns out that my Chromecast's mDNS broadcasts are unable to make it through the powerline bridge, thus I am unable to see the Chromecast as a valid casting option through apps.
I verified this through wireshark.

There are quite a few Multicast knobs on the powerline management page, but I can't seem to get the right combination of settings.

**Screenshot of Multicast Configuration Page:**
[image]

**What setting should be enabled/disabled/set to get my Chromecast/mDNS working?**

[User Manual Reference](https://nexuslinkusa.com/wp-content/uploads/GPL-2000PT-KIT_UM_V1.pdf)

Comment: Same problem here! Can't get mDNS working through the Nexuslink GPL-2000 kit. I believe mDNS queries are multicast UDP packets. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting with the factory settings, then change "Filter unknown multicast traffic" to NO.

I had to do this on both adapters. This is a pain, since they both try to sit on 192.168.0.5 by default. If you enable DHCP on each adapter's IP settings page, and restart both, they'll lease IPs from your router. Much easier to configure once each has a real IP on your network.

Here are my Multicast settings.

> [image: Screenshot of my Multicast configuration page]

Comment: Confirmed that the above setting work. I did not factory reset my adapter, but the important part was to physically unplug and replug both adapters after changing the settings.

Verified with Wireshark (that MDNS packets traversed the bridge), casting YouTube to Chromecast behind the bridge, and linking Stadia controller to Chromecast behind the bridge.